# Controller return incorrect data with ajax ActionLink in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-ajax

several days ago with searching i put an ajax button inside my page, but i didn't know the issue till now, the thing is happen, is that the result i receive is not the result from ajax redirection, but is result from first processing (though i was wonder why it do it twist)...

And what i wanna do is perform filtering through link button instead of button.

so i have two action, one is for my ajax button, and second for my index:

1.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChooseCategoryAction(int? id)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(monitorObj);
        // Save code here...
        Session.Add("FilterCategory", id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

2.

```
    public override ActionResult Index()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        int? id = (Session["FilterCategory"] != null) ? int.Parse(Session["FilterCategory"].ToString()) : (int?)null;
        List<LinkEntity> filterList = null;
        int catId = id ?? -1;
        if (catId != -1)
        {
            filterList = new List<LinkEntity>();
            foreach (LinkEntity linkEntity in linkList.Where(
                where =>
                    (catId == 0 && @where.Category == null) ||
                    (@where.Category != null && @where.Category.Id == catId)).Select(
                        select =>
                            new LinkEntity(@select.Id, @select.Name, @select.Link, @select.Description,
                                @select.Category)))
            {
                filterList.Add(linkEntity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filterList = linkList;
        }
        return View(filterList);
    }
```

My View is like this:

```
<div class="split-left">
    @if (ViewBag.CategoriesTags != null)
    {
        foreach (var cat in ViewBag.CategoriesTags)
        {
            <div class="link-item-category">
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Ajax.ActionLink((string)cat.Name, "ChooseCategoryAction","Home", new { id = cat.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new{@class = "category-link"})
                }
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

When i click the link it should goes to Ajax method, then inbox, filter my data and return a view, but it first goes to inbox, then to Ajax, again to inbox, next it goes value seem to be true, but result which return is incorrect

i also before reaching to filtering step, tried following:

```
                    @Html.Hidden(((int)cat.Id).ToString())
                    @Html.ActionLink((string)cat.Name, "ChooseCategoryAction", "Home", null, new { @class = "category-link", onclick = "return false;" })
```

with following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.category-link').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it don't return to controller or don't refresh page

Comment: I also used TempData, instead of session, but That dont work at all, with session most of time i have to click twise till it work

Comment: at last i did something answer me well, but i'm not sure if i have right to do this, and it is a good practice at my condition...   
Action link:   
`@Ajax.ActionLink((string)cat.Name, "ChooseCategoryAction","Home", new { id = cat.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "$(this).closest('form')[0].submit()"}, new{@class = "category-link"})`

   Controller:   `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public JsonResult ChooseCategoryAction(int? id){Session.Add("FilterCategory", id); return Json("{success:true}"); }`